# Struts form not working with struts tiles

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I am designing a shopping cart project in which my content area alone changes, so i configured it with struts tiles, and everything worked fine until i encountered forms in my project. when ever i tried to display forms(struts forms) using tiles. the forms didn't compile it is just coming as such `<html:text property="username"/>` please help.

My Tiles def is

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="main-layout" path="/WEB-INF/layout.jsp">
    <put name="title" value="" />
    <put name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layout/header.jsp"/>
    <put name="secmenu" value="/WEB-INF/layout/secmenu.jsp"/>
    <put name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/layout/menu.jsp"/>
    <put name="content" value=""/>
    <put name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>    
<definition name="index" extends="main-layout">
    <put name="title" value="The Mobile Store"/>
    <put name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/homecontent.jsp"/>
</definition>
<definition name="login" extends="main-layout">
    <put name="title" value=":: Login ::"/>
    <put name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp"/>        
</definition>
```

The form i used is

```
<html:form action="login.html" method="post">
    <table align="center" id="logintable">
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Your UserName : </td>
            <td><html:text property="username"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Your Password : </td>
            <td><html:password property="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                
            <td colspan="2"><html:submit value="LOGIN"/></td>                
        </tr>
    </table>            
</html:form>
```

Comment: do you have declaration of taglib at the top of the page : <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>

Comment: yes i have it in the main layout page that is layout.jsp in the above code

Comment: and use bean:write instead of html:text. for example <bean:write name="formName" property="propertyName" />

Comment: <html:password property="password"/> you didn't add form name..

Comment: name is the property field.As i said i use struts forms.

Comment: for properties use <bean:message key="password" />

Comment: could you please give in full format please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting the problem since you are trying to access the jsp file which is inside the WEB-INF folder. And if you are trying with struts 1.x try using struts 2.0. for tutorial use this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-tiles-plugin-tutorial-with-example-in-eclipse/

Comment: I am using struts that came up with netbeans 7.1.2 which is 1.3.10. How can i update the struts in netbeans? Pls Help.

Comment: Download the plugin from here http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/23467/netbeans-struts2-support

Comment: Then i need to do the entire project again from scratch ah?

Comment: If you have followed real MVC pattern then it wont be a problem thats the beauty of MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You must include tiles plugin into `struts-config`; please follow below link for more info:

http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-tiles-framework-example/

Comment: i have included the plugin into struts-config.Tiles is working fine for normal pages except for form, the problem it was unable to compile the struts form tags.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your struts config file. in your action-mapping in action tag you must specify formName. it's look something like this

```
<action-mappings>
        <action path="/Action" name="form">
```

after this in your jsp page you must add taglib `<%@taglib uri="struts.apache.org/tags-html"; prefix="html"%>`

and you can use html tag like this:

Answer (score 1):

in your struts-config write this:

```
<message-resources parameter="properties.labels" />
```

in my app labels properties is here: [image]

and in your jsp :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
```

and use bean tag like this:

```
 <bean:message key="password" />
```

Comment: what i need to have in the labels file?

Comment: labels file it is my property file. you need to have there something like this : password=1234

Comment: Actually my problem is this code <html:password property="password"/> should render as <input name="password" type="password"/> but it didn't gets compiled so it came as such like <html:password property="password"/>.The thing here is my code works good if i didn't use tiles.

Comment: I think it's impossible. because when you submit html form all info from html:password would be send to password variable. in your situation it would be send to property file(I think struts can't do this)

Comment: Then how can i add form in struts tiles. Please tell some alternatives

Comment: may be I don't understand clearly what you want to do but I think you need to do this: at first create actionForm class and create all necessary filds there with getters and setters, than you create simple jsp page with all neccessary filds by using html tags(with name parameter which would be the name of your actionform class) after you submit form in action class you check password from jsp page with password from property file(I think better to use database like MySQl) and if password is correct then redirect to welcome page or something like this

Comment: please find my project in the following url http://www.ziddu.com/download/21200911/MobileStore.rar.html. I have used netbeans IDE and weblogic server.

Comment: I think you need to look at this example: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-tiles-example-1.html

Comment: Did you found what exactly my problem is?

Comment: very hard to look at your app. Because you didn't sort all files into packages.
Your jsp files almost all are empty. You have not start page(index.jsp) and you don't write into your web.xml welcome-files.

Comment: globalforward is my index page.Import and run it using netbeans.

Comment: at first if you writing web app you must use mvc pattern. and all redirect and forwarding must go throw action class

Comment: This application too send to Action Class only.All .do requests are send to Action class.